# Unable to find the day in calendar with customized xpath on chropath. Is any one can explain why its happened?

Tags: selenium

//body/bs-datepicker-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/bs-days-calendar-view[1]/bs-calendar-layout[1]/div[2]/table[1]//tbody[1]//tr//td[contains(text(), '5')]

This my custom expath to find the day in calander td. But i am getting "zero element matching"

[image: Chropath]

[image: calender i am using]

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("//body/bs-datepicker-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/bs-days-calendar-view[1]/bs-calendar-layout[1]/div[2]/table[1]//tbody[1]//tr//td[contains(text(),'15')]")).click();
```

this is my sytax i have used

Comment: add html or url

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried so far.

Comment: d.findElement(By.xpath(DOB)).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  while(true){
  String dbmonth = d.findElement(By.xpath(DOBmonth)).getText();
  String dbyear = d.findElement(By.xpath(DOByear)).getText();
  if(dbmonth.equals(Bmonth)& dbyear.equals(Byear)) {
   break;
  }
  else
  {
   d.findElement(By.xpath(previous)).click();
  }
  }
  d.findElement(By.xpath(selectDOB + Bday )).click();